# Definition of NonNullable<T> in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

I was looking for something like a Nullable type in TypeScript when I noticed that while there is no Nullable type (or is there?), there is a `NonNullable` type defined in:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts

The definition of `NonNullable` is:

```js
/**
 * Exclude null and undefined from T
 */
type NonNullable <T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

Can someone please explain (or point me to the relevant documentation about) what this definition means? I could not locate the documentation around this. Specifically, I could not find what the `?` operator and the `never` keyword means in the context of generic constraints.

I found other similar definitions in the same file:

```
/**
 * Exclude from T those types that are assignable to U
 */
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;

/**
 * Extract from T those types that are assignable to U
 */
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

Comment: [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types)

Answer (score 2):

Someone has pointed you in the direction of conditional types which is the second part of your question but for anyone else that stumbles upon this the opposite of `NonNullable<T>` would be `T | null | undefined`, basically just saying that it can be defined as `T` or it can be `null` or `undefined`, you can read more about it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types